# Converting number with strval() return 0

Tags: php, string, int

I want to convert 0812345678 into string with strval(), but the return I get is '0'. How can I get the full string of the number? Thanks.

```
$pn = 0812345678;
$spn = strval($pn);
echo $spn ;
```

Comment: @jack it is actually a phone number

Comment: Sorry @Jack I don't know what you mean?

Comment: yes it is submitted by users :)

Comment: If it's submitted by users, it's already a string value.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers that begin with `0` are parsed as octal numbers. Since `8` isn't a valid octal digit, it stops parsing there, so the number returned is `0`; this is then converted to the string `"0"`. If you try:

```
var_dump(strval(0128));
```

the output is:

```
string(2) "10"
```

because it parses the octal number `012`, which is equal to decimal `10`.

Comment: There's no way to manipulate it. The number in an assignment is parsed at compile time. Don't put leading zeroes on decimal numbers.'